# multiple select statement sql returns 2 columns: how to add these with eachother

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this following query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM (Price) OVER () AS requestedParts
     FROM Claim
     INNER JOIN ClaimCrossTire ON Claim.ID = ClaimCrossTire.ClaimID
     INNER JOIN Tire ON ClaimCrossTire.TireID = Tire.ID
     WHERE Claim.ID = 386160) AS requestedParts,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(Cost * nCost) OVER () AS requestedLabour
     FROM Claim c 
     INNER JOIN ClaimCrossCostItem ccci ON c.ID = ccci.ClaimID
     INNER JOIN CostItem ci ON ccci.CostItemID = ci.ID
     WHERE ci.CostItemTypeID = 1 AND ClaimID = 386160) AS requestedLabour
```

This returns a result like:

```
requestedParts  requestedLabour
-------------------------------
144.000          291.000000
```

Now, I would like to add these two columns with eachother and create a third column called something like `total`, where `requestedParts` and `requestedLabour` are added so in this case it would be `total: 435.000`. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: absolutely possible. You may use a CTE or derived table to do that

Comment: thank you @Squirrel i have never used CTE before but i tried it and i managed to fix my issue, so thanks:)

Comment: Use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is logical nonsense generally. And here your use of a windowed aggregate is also over-complicated, hides your goal, and fragile due to the use of the same literal ID value in multiple places. Charlieface has a better approach but I think it can be improved by starting with a simple SELECT statement from dbo.Claim (note - always schema-qualify your object names). That is based on assumption that Claim.Id is the primary (or unique) key.

Answer (score 0):

You can place these two subqueries in the `FROM` clause and cross-join them.

I'm not able to tell without seeing your schema, but you may even be able to combine the two into a single aggrgetation

> I also removed the window functions, as using standard aggregation got the same result in this instance

```sql
SELECT
  rp.requestedParts,
  rl.requestedLabour,
  rp.requestedParts + rl.requestedLabour AS total
FROM
(
     SELECT SUM (Price) AS requestedParts
     FROM Claim
     INNER JOIN ClaimCrossTire ON Claim.ID = ClaimCrossTire.ClaimID
     INNER JOIN Tire ON ClaimCrossTire.TireID = Tire.ID
     WHERE Claim.ID = 386160
) AS rp
CROSS JOIN
(
     SELECT SUM(Cost * nCost) AS requestedLabour
     FROM Claim c 
     INNER JOIN ClaimCrossCostItem ccci ON c.ID = ccci.ClaimID
     INNER JOIN CostItem ci ON ccci.CostItemID = ci.ID
     WHERE ci.CostItemTypeID = 1 AND ClaimID = 386160
) AS rl;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my idea.
you can write these lines

```sql
SELECT  Result.requestedLabour,Result.requestedParts,
Result.requestedLabour+Result.requestedParts as Total
FROM (

SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM (Price) OVER () AS requestedParts
     FROM Claim
     INNER JOIN ClaimCrossTire ON Claim.ID = ClaimCrossTire.ClaimID
     INNER JOIN Tire ON ClaimCrossTire.TireID = Tire.ID
     WHERE Claim.ID = 386160) AS requestedParts,
    (SELECT TOP 1 SUM(Cost * nCost) OVER () AS requestedLabour
     FROM Claim c 
     INNER JOIN ClaimCrossCostItem ccci ON c.ID = ccci.ClaimID
     INNER JOIN CostItem ci ON ccci.CostItemID = ci.ID
     WHERE ci.CostItemTypeID = 1 AND ClaimID = 386160) AS requestedLabour
     
) as Result
```